# Matlab cosine mistake

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I've got some problem while equaling such function as:

```
function  czeb()
k = 1:1:5;
Xk = cos( (pi*(k-0.5))/5);
CN(5,Xk)
end

function c = CN(N,x)
a=N*acos(x); % a is equal correct
c = cos(a);  % buc c not, why?
return
end
```

If I view variable a inside CN function I receive 
`a=[1.5708, 4.7124, 7.8540, 10.9956, 14.1372]`
 which is correct bun next step in CN function is to calculate cos(a).

In this step I receive incorrect value of cos(a).

It should be 
`cos(a) = 1.0e-04 *[-0.0367,0.1102,-0.1837,0.2571,-0.3306]`

but it is `1.0e-15 * [-0.8269,-0.1837,0.3062,-0.4286,0.5511]` and I don't know why...

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking here.

Comment: if you start that function inside CN a will be a vector like a=[1.5708    4.7124, 7.8540, 10.9956,14.1372], cos(a(1)) = -3.6732e-06, but CN function receive  1.0e-15 * -0.8269

Comment: PatLas, please edit your question to clearly state what you expected and why and what you got instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple explanation, and you function is not wrong.

```
a=[1.5708, 4.7124, 7.8540, 10.9956, 14.1372]
```

is equal to `pi/2 + k * pi`. When you take the cosine of a, you will just get zeros. `1.0e-15 * 0.8269` is essentially zero (floating point arithmetic, and rounding errors).

Answer (score 1):

I think, I understand your. Have you have create expected values manual, like `cos(1.5708)`? If yes, then you will always receive different results with results made by your computer. So, I think, your expected values of array `a` are incorrect.

First, enable long number format in the MATLAB/Octave:

```
format long;
```

After that, if you display your `a` array, you will see the similar output:

```
> a
a = 
  1.57079632679490  4.71238898038469  7.85398163397448 10.99557428756428 14.13716694115407
```

As you see at this step, your expected values and computed values by MATLAB/Octave are different. Than, if you do `cos(1.57079632679490)` the result will like `-3.49148336110938e-15` and, as you see, this is near to the result of `cos(a(1))`: `-8.26948102009006e-16`. This means, that your stored number is different with that you see in the output.

To instead receive the same results as you expect - round your `a` to the fourth number after comma:

```
a = round(a*10000)/10000;
```

With this the computed results should be near to your expected results.